# The Favorite is disappeared from the sidebar of the download and upload window of the browser

Tags: mac, finder

The favorite is disappeared from the sidebar of the download and upload window of all browser, either Chrome and Safar.

You can see in the screenshots that I attached.

I can see favorite on the sidebar of the normal finder.

I don't know what happened.

Anyone who know how to solve this problem??

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I occasionally have found the solution lol.

After restarting, everything is fine.

I'll just leave this post for someone who might be suffering ths same issue.